# How do the invitations from GitHub followers work?

Tags: support, jobs

My question is pretty simple. When do you get extra invitations on Careers 2.0 for GitHub followers? And how many?

And is this being kept track of? If so at what interval does it check the GitHub profiles?

Or is this information all hush hush?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well it depends :)

We give out invitations for a number of reasons including followers on your open source repositories. BUT we don't give you all the invitations at once. If you've gotten invitations for one reason, we hold off granting you invitations for your second reason for a minimum of 7 days. Another 7 days for your third reason, etc etc.

So if you've gotten an invitation grant for a reason other than open source followers, then immediately added a Github repo with the requisite number of followers you'd have to wait 7 days.

We check all your open source repositories once a day to see if they've crossed the follower threshold.

The number of invitations granted is based on the number of followers you have.